# value of textarea in loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

html and php:

```
foreach($questions as $question)
{
      ?><br><textarea class="answer">Answer here...</textarea><button data-id="<?php echo $question->id;?>"class="addanswer">Post</button><?php 
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on('click','.addanswer',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer=$('textarea.answer').val();
    var q_id=$(this).data('id');
    alert(answer);
    alert(q_id);
```

I got the text i enter in the textarea for first question. For all other questions it only alerts Answer here... even though i got the expected q_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
var answer=$('textarea.answer').val();
```

This will always give your the value of the first `$('textarea.answer')` element that jQuery encounters; it not linked to the clicked button in any way.

You want the value of the element next to the button you clicked, so with this html structure, you could use:

```
var answer = $(this).prev().val();
```

Comment: so, i need not have to assign class to textarea too.

Comment: @Steve In this example it is not strictly necessary but I would probably do it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each textarea/button in a parent node.
btw. very dirty code ;-)

```
// PHP:
$template = '<div><textarea class="answer">Answer here...</textarea><button data-id="%ID%" class="addanswer">Post</button></div>';

foreach( $questions as $question )
    echo str_replace( '%ID%', $question->id, $template );


// JQUERY:

$(document).on('click','.addanswer',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer=$('textarea.answer', this.parentNode).val();
    var q_id=$(this).data('id');
    alert(answer);
    alert(q_id);

    ....
```